# PYTHON- Return minimum three digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want to return minium three digits maximum whatever it has it should return.

I have tried following function,

```
def get_code(model, prefix):
    content = model.objects.filter(code__startswith=prefix).last()
    last = None
    code_prefix = prefix
    if content:
        a_string = content.code
        split_strings = []
        n = len(prefix)
        for index in range(0, len(a_string), n):
            split_strings.append(a_string[index: index + n])
        last = int(split_strings[1])
    if last is not None:
        suggested = last + 1
    else:
        suggested = 1
    return "{}{:03d}".format(code_prefix, suggested)
```

Above code returns threedigits only if i have 4 didits it skips for calculation also. it takes only three digits for calucualtion also. how can i fix this???

Comment: How do you run it? What output do you get? We can't read your mind, so most of your prose is meaningless except to you, and the code is not complete enough to know what you did to break it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a [mcve], as laid out in [ask]

Comment: Your comment means nothing to me. I have no idea what datatypes you are even using.

Comment: ex. content = "XXX1200". I am expecting it will return "XXX1201". But it returns "XXX121". here I should follow one coditions after string it should have minimum three digits.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the last line with

```
while len(""+suggested)<3:
    suggested="0"+suggested
return code_prefix+suggested
```

I think you will have the formatting that you want.
We have to concatenate to a string to use len and to keep the 0's.

Comment: Thanks. actually i did something wrong in logically.

Answer (score 1):

here my answer,

```
def get_code(model, prefix):
    content = model.objects.filter(code__startswith=prefix).last()

    def text_num_split(item):
        for index, letter in enumerate(item, 0):
            if letter.isdigit():
                return [item[:index], item[index:]]
    last = None
    code_prefix = prefix
    if content:
        a_string = content.code
        pre_code = text_num_split(a_string)
        last = int(pre_code[-1])
    if last is not None:
        suggested = last + 1
    else:
        suggested = 1
    return "{}{:03d}".format(code_prefix, suggested
```